# Articles in A, B, and C form

Tags: articles

In a form `A, B, and C`, do I need to use articles in all A, B, C?

> This model is an abstraction of a lower hardware layer, an upper software layer, and a connection between them.

Or can I skip some?

> This model is an abstraction of a lower hardware layer, upper software layer, and a connection between them.

Or all but one?

> This model is an abstraction of a lower hardware layer, upper software layer, and connection between them.

Comment: All three articles are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course theorecitally you are obliged to use them, but when you talk to somebody in informal language, you can sometimes skip them. But if you want to make your statement very precise and correct gramatically you can't skip them in any case.